# Json: Type 'String' is not a subtype of expected type 'int'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have an error when I run the project. The error that I get is 
`Type 'String' is not a subtype of expected type 'int' of index` could someone please tell me what I did wrong. I've searched for solutions and found a few solutions which I've tried but didn't solve the problem. 
This is the first solution that I've tried but gave the same error.

```
 factory Prayer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Prayer(
      fajr: json['data'][0]['timings']['Fajr'].toString(),
      duhr: json['data'][0]['timings']['Dhuhr'].toString(),
      asr: json['data'][0]['timings']['Asr'].toString(),
      maghrib: json['data'][0]['timings']['Maghrib'].toString(),
      isha: json['data'][0]['timings']['Isha'].toString()
    );
  }
```

and this is the second solution that i found but didn't solve my problem

```
factory Prayer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Prayer(
      fajr: json['Fajr'].toString(),
      duhr: json['Dhuhr'].toString(),
      asr: json['Asr'].toString(),
      maghrib: json['Maghrib'].toString(),
      isha: json['Isha'].toString()
    );
  }
```

This is my code:

prayerpage.dart

```
FutureBuilder<List<Prayer>>(
                  future: fetchPrayers(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<Prayer> prayer = snapshot.data;
                      return Column(
                          children: prayer.map((p) => Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(p.fajr),
                            Text(p.duhr),
                            Text(p.asr),
                            Text(p.maghrib),
                            Text(p.isha),
                            Text('ok'),
                          ])).toList(),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                    }
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  })
```

Prayer

```
class Prayer {
  String fajr;
  String duhr;
  String asr;
  String maghrib;
  String isha;
  Prayer({this.fajr,this.duhr,this.asr,this.maghrib,this.isha});



  factory Prayer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Prayer(
      fajr: json['data']['timings']['Fajr'].toString(),
      duhr: json['data']['timings']['Dhuhr'].toString(),
      asr: json['data']['timings']['Asr'].toString(),
      maghrib: json['data']['timings']['Maghrib'].toString(),
      isha: json['data']['timings']['Isha'].toString()
    );
  }  
}
```

fetchprayers

```
Future<List<Prayer>> fetchPrayers() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'http://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=Antwerpen&country=Belgium&method=2&month=03&year=2020');
    var responsejson = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return (responsejson['data']['timings'] as List)
          .map((p) => Prayer.fromJson(p))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Prayers');
    }
  }
```

this is the JSON file

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
   "code": 200,
   "status": "OK",
   "data": [{
       "timings": {
           "Fajr": "03:57",
           "Sunrise": "05:46",
           "Dhuhr": "12:59",
           "Asr": "16:55",
           "Sunset": "20:12",
           "Maghrib": "20:12",
           "Isha": "22:02",
           "Imsak": "03:47",
           "Midnight": "00:59"
       },
       "date": {
           "readable": "24 Apr 2014",
           "timestamp": "1398332113",
           "gregorian": {
               "date": "15-05-2018",
               "format": "DD-MM-YYYY",
               "day": "15",
               "weekday": {
                   "en": "Tuesday"
               },
               "month": {
                   "number": 5,
                   "en": "May",
               },
               "year": "2018",
               "designation": {
                   "abbreviated": "AD",
                   "expanded": "Anno Domini",
               },
           },
           "hijri": {
               "date": "01-09-1439",
               "format": "DD-MM-YYYY",
               "day": "01",
               "weekday": {
                   "en": "Al Thalaata",
                   "ar": "الثلاثاء",
               },
               "month": {
                   "number": 9,
                   "en": "Ramaḍān",
                   "ar": "رَمَضان",
               },
               "year": "1439",
               "designation": {
                   "abbreviated": "AH",
                   "expanded": "Anno Hegirae",
               },
               "holidays": [
                   "1st Day of Ramadan"
               ],
           },
       },
```

Comment: What is the line throwing this error ? It means that you're giving a String to something that needs an int.

Comment: What is the shape of your JSON?

Comment: oh sorry, forget to add the JSON file. I will add it now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This for you **fetchPrayers**

```
Future<List<Prayer>> fetchPrayers() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      'http://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=Antwerpen&country=Belgium&method=2&month=03&year=2020');
  var responsejson = json.decode(response.body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> data = responsejson["data"] as List<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> ;
    return data.map((element) => Prayer.fromJson(element["timings"])).toList();

  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load Prayers');
  }
}
```

And use this for your **Prayer.fromJson** factory constructor

```
factory Prayer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Prayer(
      fajr: json['Fajr'].toString(),
      duhr: json['Dhuhr'].toString(),
      asr: json['Asr'].toString(),
      maghrib: json['Maghrib'].toString(),
      isha: json['Isha'].toString()
    );
  }
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: no, it gives me another error ```type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<Map<String,Map<String, Object>>>' ```